# Incorrect mongoose types when using generic documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make a class that, among other things, creates a mongoose model with a property that uses a dynamic type. I'm currently using a generic `V` to establish the type, and a property in the constructor to establish what to actually put in the Schema. For example: `new MyClass<string>(String)`

However, I get a typescript error whenever I try to use the created model in the class (but not outside of it). Here's an example of the type of class I'm making:

```
// use generics to specify the dynamic type
interface SampleDocument<V> extends Document {
  someValue: V;
}

class ModelTester<V> {
  public Model: Model<SampleDocument<V>>;

  // `sampleValue` is just so I'll have something to put in the `findOne()`
  // function so I can show what doesn't work
  public constructor(name: string, valueType: unknown, sampleValue: V) {
    const schema = new Schema({
      someValue: valueType,
    });

    this.Model = model<SampleDocument<V>>(name, schema);
    this.Model.findOne({ someValue: sampleValue }); // ts error
  }
}

const { Model: Sample } = new ModelTester('Sample', String, 'test');
Sample.findOne({ someValue: '' }); // no ts error
```

> Argument of type '{ someValue: V; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '_FilterQuery<_AllowStringsForIds<Pick<Pick<_LeanDocument<SampleDocument>, "_id" | "__v" | "id" | "someValue">, Exclude<"_id", FunctionPropertyNames<SampleDocument>> | Exclude<...> | Exclude<...> | Exclude<...>>>>'.
>
> Type '{ someValue: V; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in keyof _AllowStringsForIds<Pick<Pick<_LeanDocument<SampleDocument>, "_id" | "__v" | "id" | "someValue">, Exclude<"_id", FunctionPropertyNames<SampleDocument>> | Exclude<...> | Exclude<...> | Exclude<...>>>]?: (P extends "_id" ? [...] extends [...] ? Condition<...> : Condition<...> : [...] extends [...] ...

This error does not occur if I leave out the generics and hardcode the types to, for example, a string.

```
interface SampleDocument extends Document {
  someValue: string;
}

class ModelTester {
  public Model: Model<SampleDocument>;

  public constructor(name: string, valueType: unknown, sampleValue: string) {
    const schema = new Schema({
      someValue: valueType,
    });

    this.Model = model<SampleDocument>(name, schema);
    this.Model.findOne({ someValue: sampleValue }); // no ts error
  }
}

const { Model: Sample } = new ModelTester('Sample', String, 'test');
Sample.findOne({ someValue: '' }); // no ts error
```

Comment: How does the `ModelTester` class know that the `valueType` matches the `sampleValue`?  That's a problem.  I can call `new ModelTester('Sample', Number, 'test')` without error, but `findOne({ someValue: 'test'})` is and should be an error.  I fixed that by unfortunately I still have the error: https://tsplay.dev/m3Aa1w

Comment: If you have a solution in mind for that issue I'd love to hear it (I'm stumped)! However, I don't really think it affects the current error I'm getting.

Comment: My inclination is that the issue is that `V` could be a union.  Generic unions are a problem that's really hard to solve.  If `V` is `number | string` then you could have `valueType: Number` `sampleValue: test`.  So you might need to just assert your way out.

Comment: This is why it fails, is because you can call `new ModelTester<string | number>('Sample', Number, 'test');` https://tsplay.dev/wXR29m

Comment: Ah, never would've thought of that. This is quite the pickle. Thanks for your help!